# How to submit data of a form with repeated field names?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a table in which every row has an option to upload a CSV file and a button to generate the report.
So every row has a file input with same name "file" and a button to submit the form. This file should be uploaded corresponding to the other values in the row. But when I was trying to upload the file on server side PHP unable to detects a uploaded file.
The current workaround that is working is creating a different form for every row.But isn't there a way to get it done by one form? Is it good to have too many forms on a single HTML page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do this is to turn the input name attributes into arrays with `[]`:

```
<input type='text' name='input[]' />
```

Then in PHP, access them as:

```
// $_POST['input'] is an array...
foreach ($_POST['input'] as $input_value) {
}
```

For file inputs, they'll appear as an array in `$_FILES`:

```
<input type='file' name='infile[]' />

// $_FILES['infile'] is an array
foreach ($_FILES['infile'] as $f) {
  echo $f['tmpname'];
  echo $f['size']';
  // etc....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) you can do it by adding `[]` in the name.

Comment: IMO, this answer should be converted to a comment under the question or outright deleted.  Michael's answer is clearly more generous because it actually implements a solution.  The only value in this answer is that it provides a hyperlink to the PHP manual, but Stack Overflow does not intend to be a traffic router for the internet.